# How to save a gt table to either an excel or word file

Tags: gtsummary

After submitting my beautiful tables to a publisher, they want them in either a word or excel file. Is there a simple way to save a gt table to either format or am I better off just redoing them in excel?

Comment: The `gt::gtsave()` function can save your table in RTF format that is compatible with Word. RTF output is not yet 100% supported and some extra fancy formatting options may not yet be supported. But you'll still get a nice table.

Answer (score 7):

Here are some options for exporting gtsummary tables to excel or RTF:

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(writexl)

gt_table <- trial %>% 
  tbl_summary() 

# Export to Excel ----

# convert to tibble, then write to xlsx
gt_table %>%
  gtsummary::as_tibble() %>% 
  writexl::write_xlsx(., "example_gtsummary1.xlsx")

# Or use `as_hux_xlsx()`
gt_table %>% 
  as_hux_xlsx("example_gtsummary2.xlsx")
                         
# Export to RTF ----
gt_table %>%
  gtsummary::as_gt() %>% 
  gt::gtsave(., "example_gtsummary3.rtf")
```

More details about the first option in this post: https://www.pipinghotdata.com/posts/2021-07-14-polished-summary-tables-in-r-with-gtsummary/

Comment: I made a gt table with a gt_plt_sparkline. I've tried to export it to excel, word or pdf and it's not working. Do you know how can I do ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for a solution to this (specifically how to get GT tables into Excel), and I've just discovered that Excel can open HTML tables. So if you don't have lots of tables, you could just export them all as HTML, open them in Excel and then save them as .xlsx files.

Answer (score 0):

When used within an R Markdown file, `gt` and `gtsummary` objects knit nicely to Word by calling the `flextable` package.

````
---
title: "GT tables to word"
output:
  word_document: default
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

library(gtsummary)
library(openxlsx)

```

## Example tables to output

```{r tabs}
## Summary tables
trial |> 
      select(age, grade, response, trt) |> 
      tbl_summary(
        by = trt,
        label = list(age ~ "Patient Age"),
        statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})"),
        digits = list(age ~ c(0, 1))
      )
```


```{r regression}
## Regression output
glm(response ~ trt, trial, family = binomial) |> 
      tbl_regression(
        exponentiate = TRUE,
        label = list(trt ~ "Treatment (unadjusted)")
      )

```
````

Can write a list of `gt` or `gtsummary` objects as separate sheets in a single workbook using the `openxlsx` packgae:

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(openxlsx)

## Example tables to output
tabs <- list(
  
  ## Summary tables
  t1 =  trial |> 
    select(age, grade, response, trt) |> 
    tbl_summary(
      by = trt,
      label = list(age ~ "Patient Age"),
      statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})"),
      digits = list(age ~ c(0, 1))
    ),
  
  ## Regression output
  t2 = glm(response ~ trt, trial, family = binomial) |> 
    tbl_regression(
      exponentiate = TRUE,
      label = list(trt ~ "Treatment (unadjusted)")
    )
)

## Output to excel using openxlsx package
lapply(tabs, as_tibble) |> 
  openxlsx::write.xlsx(file = "Test_output.xlsx")
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>